# ubuntu black screen appears

Tags: cpu

I am using ubuntu 12.4 in that we have installed 2Gb RAM dual core processor I have installed some of the software like eclipse , SQL . while using these software's few seconds screen goes into black and then turning into normal I have even checked memory it is only around 50% why this is happening like that and their is any solution for this ?

Comment: Take a look at the answers to this question: [How to minimize services in Ubuntu](http://superuser.com/questions/230624/how-to-minimize-services-in-ubuntu). The question is also specific to Eclipse.